# Maximo automation script - commtemplate with parameters

Tags: python, automation, maximo

In Maximo 7.5 ,I'm trying to call a communication template via automation script.
My communication template takes 3 parameters, how can I pass it in automation script.

```
from psdi.server import MXServer
from psdi.mbo import SqlFormat
from java.text import MessageFormat
""" get three parameters that are required for mail and get value of  primaryEmail"""
whereclause="templateid='WMSPWUSER'";
csr =mbo.getMboSet("$commtemp","COMMTEMPLATE",whereclause);
csr.setQbeExactMatch("true");
if csr.count() > 0 :     
   print("Inside commtemplate");
   ctr = csr.getMbo(0);
   sqf =SqlFormat(ctr.getString("message").replace("'", "''"));
   sqf.setIgnoreUnresolved(1);
   message = sqf.resolveContent();
   args = [ param1, param2,param3 ];
   MessageFormat fmt = new MessageFormat(message);
   message = fmt.format(args);
   MXServer.sendEMail( primaryEmail , ctr.getString("sendfrom"),    ctr.getString("subject"), message);
```

works via java customization.

Line message=fmt.format(args) is throwing error in python automation script.

Error Message: BMXAA7837E - An error occured that prevented the  script for the launch point from running.
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.python.core.PyList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object; in  at line number 19

```
message = sqf.resolveContent();
args = [ pwd, login,url ];
fmt = MessageFormat(message);
message = fmt.format(args); """ line 19"""
```

Comment: I am not able to look into this to see the correct way to do it, but knowing the python error message you got could help me point you in the right direction, maybe.

Comment: You're leaving us to assume that you ported the code correctly. Along with the error message, it would help if you provided the corresponding python snippet, including the `import`s

Comment: updated the script with more details